# Include object from pointer which is item of an object within an array

Tags: parse-platform

I'm working with the JS-SDK of parse and have following data-structure in the database:

```
{"ingredients":
  [
    {"amount": 100, "name": "sugar", "unit": {"__type":"Pointer","className":"Unit","objectId":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}},
    {"amount": 300, "name": "milk", "unit": {"__type":"Pointer","className":"Unit","objectId":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}}
  ]
}
```

"ingredients" is the array column of a Recipe Class.

How would I have to query for the Recipe to have the "unit"-object included as well? Here is what I've got so far:

```
var Recipe = Parse.Object.extend("Recipe"),
    RecipeQuery = new Parse.Query(Recipe);
RecipeQuery.include("ingredients");
RecipeQuery.include("ingredients.unit");
RecipeQuery.find(...);
```

I hope someone can help me out here, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data structure was like:

```
{"ingredients":
  [
    {"__type":"Pointer", "className":"Unit", "objectId":"FKxndF7X9H"},
    {"__type":"Pointer", "className":"Unit", "objectId":"mXVGZDglZN"} 
  ]
}
```

Then you would be able to take these units by using only `recipeQuery.include("ingredients");`. It would retrieve all nested objects in the array. However, this approach doesn't work when you put dictionaries into the array as you did.

I believe one solution could be to create a new array field called `units` in `Recipe`. This gets `unit` out of the `ingredients` array. So you will have two arrays `ingredients` and `units`.

Other solution could be to create a new class. Something like `Ingredient` which has `name`, `amount` and `unit` fields. The `ingredients` array would contain pointers to `Ingredient` objects.

Comment: First of all, thx for your answer.
Your first solution wouldn't help me because i would lose track which ingredient had which unit.
I also thought of the second solution (via Ingredient Class) but I'm still hoping for a possibility to avoid this ;)

Comment: You wouldn't actually lose track which ingredient had which unit. While filling the units array, use the same order of the ingredients array. Ingredient[0] unit will be in units[0].

Comment: Oh, of course, you're right! I'll give it a shot tomorrow!

Comment: Solved it with a second Ingredient-Class. Thanks for the help!